# Yii2 select2.How to select multiple items without closing the selection dropdown

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I am using yii2 select2 in my project.And the code is

```
<?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'drp-amenties',
        'data' => Amenties::getAmentiesEnglish(),
        'options' => [
          'id'=>'drp-amenties',
          'placeholder' => 'Select Amenties',
          'multiple' => true
        ]
      ]); ?>
```

And the output is like this [image: please check this image].

The code is working. When I click the select2 it opens the selection dropdown as shown in the image. I can select multiple items. But the problem is I can only select items one by one. Means when I select one item, the select dropdown is closing. And then I want to click the select2 to open the dropdown for selecting the section item. I want it like selecting multiple items for the first time opening.

Comment: We can hold "ctrl key" for multiple selection at once

Comment: Personally, i switched from kartik to bootstrap-select. It allow you to do exactly what you asking about. Check it out: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes

Comment: What about setting `closeOnSelect` option of select2 to `false`? To set select2 options you have to use `pluginOptions` property of `Select2` widget so it will look like `'pluginOptions' => ['closeOnSelect' => false],`.